# Input loses placeholder after double-click

Tags: javascript

On click placeholder disappears, on blur it reappears, but if double-click happens instead of 1 click placeholder just disappears forever, turning off double-click default doesn't help either. Is it somehow possible to treat double-click as normal click? Or is it supposed to destroy placehoder?

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
input.onclick = function() {
  p_holder = this.placeholder;
  this.placeholder = "";
}

input.onblur = function() {
  this.placeholder = p_holder;
}

input.ondblclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text goes here">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

Comments are in the source code.

```js
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
// Store original placeholder
var p_holder = input.placeholder;
// Remove on focus
input.onfocus = function() {
  this.placeholder = "";
}
// Restore on blur
input.onblur = function() {
  this.placeholder = p_holder;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text goes here" />
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I well get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Perfect, onfocus did it!

Answer (score 0):

It is not double click, but two single clicks which are causing this issue, because on the second click, the value of `p_holder` will be set to `''`.

To prevent that, you can check for the value first:

```
input.onclick = function (){
  if (this.placeholder !== '') {
    p_holder = this.placeholder;
    this.placeholder = "";
  }
}
```

By the way, if you just need to deal with placeholder, you actually don't need to manipulate it. The browser automatically removes it when some value is inserted into the input, and restores it when the value is removed.